# How to play downloaded audio file using react-native-fs?

Tags: react-native, audio, download, filesystems

I have a issue in using react-native-fs.

Download audio file using react-native-fs and this working well:

```
    let audio_filename = track_item.url.split('/').pop();
    const downloadDest_audio = `${RNFS. DocumentDirectoryPath}/${global.audio_dir}/${audio_filename}`;

    const progress = data => {
        const percentage = ((100 * data.bytesWritten) / data.contentLength) | 0;
        console.log(`Progress  ${percentage}% `)
    };

    const begin = res => {

    };

    const progressDivider = 1;
    const background = false;

    //////////  download audio file  /////////
    let ret_audio = RNFS.downloadFile({ fromUrl: track_item.url, toFile: downloadDest_audio, begin, progress, background, progressDivider });
    await ret_audio.promise.then(res => {
        console.log("file://" + downloadDest_audio)
    }).catch(err => {

    });
```

And after I am trying to play audio file which is generated from above code using [react-native-track-player](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player).

```
await TrackPlayer.add({
    ... ... ...,
    url: "file://" + downloadDest_audio,
    ... ... ...
});
await TrackPlayer.play();
```

But TrackPlayer is in Buffering state and not play audio file. TrackPlayer is working well from server url.

Please advance me if anyone knows this issue. Thanks

Comment: Are you having this issue on iOS or Android?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't work on ios and I don't run app on android yet.

Comment: Then, try removing file://. It's not needed on iOS

Comment: Also I tried it, but it's same.

Comment: @WaterFlower you got any solution to this ?